# Strange folder path directory error migrating from Startup.cs to Program.cs Minimal Hosting Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-6.0, asp.net-core-minimal-hosting-model

I have moved to ASP.NET Core 6 for my MVC application and I am having a strange issue for defining my enviroment path to use when setting a file provider. My code is as follows:

```
var RootPath = builder.Environment.ContentRootPath;
var WebPath = builder.Environment.WebRootPath;
var applicationRoot = Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(RootPath).ToString(), "Files");
IFileProvider physicalProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(applicationRoot);
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IFileProvider>(physicalProvider);
```

When doing this my RootPath is the correct directory but applicationRoot returns the same result so its as if GetParent() is doing nothing. My old code which I was converting which has always worked is as follows:

```
        var applicationRoot = Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(env.ContentRootPath).ToString(), "Files");
        IFileProvider physicalProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(applicationRoot);
        services.AddSingleton<IFileProvider>(physicalProvider);
```

Comment: I have reproduced your issue accordingly, it's quite surprising, still not getting why its getting the wrong path. However, I got another way to get the parent in `dotnet 6`.

Comment: Yea I figured out another way as well but this issue is definitely strange.

Comment: Yes I agree with you, looks strange.However, `DirectoryInfo(env.ContentRootPath).Parent.ToString()` it leads to expected result.